# How to minify css files using MVC .NET Bundle Conifig file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

i have the below code in my BundleConfig.cs file. the current configuration settings concatenates all the files into a single file, but i want that single file to be minified also,so that the file size will be reduced and performance will be increased.

```
        bundles.Add(
            new StyleBundle(
                "~/Contents/css/style-bundle").Include("~/Contents/css/reset.css",
                                                       "~/Contents/css/page1.css",
                                                       "~/Contents/css/page2.css"));
```

Comment: It will be automatically minified when in production.

Comment: No it is minified, it is just concatenated

Comment: Did u try online minifiers like http://www.minifier.org/

Comment: All white space, comments etc is removed - what else do you expect with a css file?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your code of bottom

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

minify js also css.

Comment: OP has mentioned that *Bundling is working by concatenating files into a single file.* But your provided code is related to *[Enabling bundling in debug mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#controlling-bundling-and-minification)*

Comment: https://github.com/deanhume/html-minifier

here is .exe file to configure into publish profile xml. when you publish your code, automated, html,chhtml,js,css file minify and put on your respective location.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't have a minified file at all on your solution. First copy each css text on minifier site like: [CSS Minifier](https://cssminifier.com/) or [Minifier](http://www.minifier.org/). Then add this to your solution with `min` word on the filename like:

```
page1-min.css
```

You don't necessarily need to add this on your bundle since ASP.NET will do this for you when in release mode.

Make sure you are on `release mode` before you run your application and check your page source.